# knockoutJS binding doesn't work if data-toggle=buttons used in bootstrap for radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I am using knockout binding for radio button with bootstrap.

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input class="radio-inline" type="radio" data-bind="checked:daysBackParameter" value="true" name="daysradio" >{{texts.showAll}}
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input class="radio-inline" type="radio" data-bind="checked:daysBackParameter" value="30" name="daysradio" >{{texts.showOnly30Days}}
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input class="radio-inline" type="radio" data-bind="checked:daysBackParameter" value="60" name="daysradio" >{{texts.showOnly60Days}}
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <input class="radio-inline" type="radio" data-bind="checked:daysBackParameter" value="90" name="daysradio" >{{texts.showOnly90Days}}
            </label>
            <!--
            <label class="btn btn-default">
                <span style="cursor:pointer" data-bind="click: function(){ filterClick(30) } ,css: { 'selectedFilter' : filterValue == 30 }"><u>30 </u></span>&nbsp;
            </label>
            -->
    </div>
```

the probelm is when i use `data-toggle=buttons` then data-bind is not working
but if i remove this then data-binding works.
but in that case radio button style comes but i need button styles.
Could you please suggest any solution?

[image: want first one not the second one, second one pass the value but first one donot]

Comment: You need custom binding handlers if you're going to share control of the DOM. See http://jsfiddle.net/ervwalter/ccjnj/

Comment: @RoyJ link broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the mentioned custom binding and it worked for me. The deatails custom binding will be found on this [custom biding by Roy J](http://jsfiddle.net/ervwalter/ccjnj/)

```
<div class="btn-group" data-bind="radio: userType">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-value="company">Main User</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-value="person">Dummy user</button>
```

Comment: Problem with this solution is if this is a form and UserType is a field, the field doesn't get assigned the selected value.